# linux " close failed in file object destructor" error in python script

Tags: python, linux

On running below block of code :

```
import os
import sys
p = os.popen('ps -aef',"r")
process_not_running = 1
for item in p:
    if item.find("./yowsup-cli demos -c config -e") > -1 :
        process_not_running = 0
        break

if process_not_running == 1:
    p = os.popen("python /home/ubuntu/workspace/yowsup/yowsup-cli demos -c config -e")
```

I  am getting an error message

**close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr**

Since i am using popen for the first time.I don't know how to handle this in my code.Can anyone help me with the approach

Comment: I would highly recommend using https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil instead of opening a pipe to `ps`

Comment: At least in C, popen, must be closed with pclose, perhaps in python is the same.